# How to make different scales (interval) on x axis and y axis for scatter plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

There are two continuous variables (A and B) in my data. I want to make a scatter plot with a regression line in R. I think this is easy. But how can I make different scales (interval) for A on X axis and for B on y axis? For instance, A on X axis: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, the interval is 2.  How can I change it to: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 where the interval is 1. It is similar for y axis.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using base graphics, ggplot2 or lattice to make your plots?

Answer (score 1):

There are good instructions at [Robert Kabacoff's site](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html).  In a nutshell, you could use code such as:

```
z  =  c(1:10)
plot (A,B) #add whatever specifications you need
axis (1, at=z, labels=z)  #1 indicates the lower horizontal axis;  1=bottom, 2=left, 3=top, 4=right
```